# Have trouble concating two arrys in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have some trouble when concating two arrays in my `store.js`
I have a to do list app that i want to get the first data from `apiTask` and then when creating new tasks it will concat apiTask with tasks.
But it will show all properties after adding one task and the created task will be disappeared by adding the new one.
I would appreciate if someone can help me with it.
[i have created a code sandbox of my project.](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-feather-kum31r?file=/components/Task.vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
ADD_TASK(state, task) {
    state.tasks.unshift({
        id: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999)),
        title: task.title,
        type: task.type,
        value: task.value,
        done: false
    })
  },
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Answer (score 1):

try to separate your adding-new-task logic and setting apiTasks to tasks logic into two mutations. call the mutation with `state.tasks = state.apiTasks` assigning in your `index.vue` created/mounted hook

[here's the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-leaf-z8z2mu?file=/store/index.js)